# Перегрузка оператора c#

Tags: c#, структуры-данных

Есть класс Stack(стек реализованный на основе массива)(поля: массив stackArr и счётчик count). В нём реализован метод Pop(извлечение элемента из стека)

```cs
public int Pop(){
    int item=stackArr[--count];
    stackArr[count]=0;
    return item;
}
```

Как перегрузить декремент для извлечения элемента из стека?

Comment: Декремент чего? И как он должен работать? И что сами пыталсь?

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Сам пытался сделать, но выдавало ошибку преобразования типов

Comment: декремент типа такого `myStack--` разворачивается в выражение `myStack = myStack - 1`, то есть у унарной операции декремента возвращаемый тип операции должен совпадать с типом, на котором делаете перегрузку.

Comment: Можно пример кода для перегрузки?